# <async-supported> Element in web.xml Doesn't Seem to Work

Tags: java, xml, asynchronous, jetty, web.xml

I'm experimenting with setting up servlets in Jetty and wated to try out the async functionality only to receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: !asyncSupported: main.AsynchronousServlet@6d39e108==main.AsynchronousServlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=true
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.startAsync(Request.java:2232)
    at...
```

From what I understand I need to add an element to the web.xml (Another concept I am unfamiliar with) setting async-supported, so I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AsynchronousServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>main.AsynchronousServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AsynchronousServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AsynchronousServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However, I still get the same error. I have no filters, so some of the other answers I found don't apply, and I know the web.xml is in the right place because if I misspell the class name I get a different error.
Would somebody help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm using jetty-9.4.3.v20170317

Comment: What version of jetty?

Comment: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317

Comment: Do you have any Filters in play? or annotations declared on the `AsynchronousServlet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the following line:

```
@WebServlet("/SynchronousServlet")
```

Cannot be used here. Seems to conflict with the web.xml